# Solving $10x \equiv 1 \pmod{11^2}$

Tags: number-theory

$$10x \equiv 1 \pmod{11^2}$$

I know $10x \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$.

I Have $x \equiv 109 \pmod{11^2}$ but this took me a lot of time to find.

Is there a quicker way?

Comment: $10x\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ iff $-x\equiv 1$ iff $x\equiv -1\pmod{11}$. Now need to lift to $11^2$.

Comment: How are we supposed to know if there is a way quicker then the one you didn't show us?

Comment: I just guessed $109$ so not really a method

Comment: You can simplify the above equation to: $$121k + 1 = 10x$$ Now you look for a number $k$ such that $121k$ ends with 9. 9 comes first in mind and it is the smallest such number.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How do I lift to $11^2$?

Comment: Look for $10(-1+11t)\equiv 1\pmod{11^2}$, which is equivalent to $(10)(11)t\equiv 11\pmod{11^2}$, which is equivalent to $10t\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, so $t\equiv -1$, get $x=-1-11$. Wanted to mention lifting because it is a general procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The systematic way is to use the extended Euclidean algorithm for $\gcd(10,11^2)$ and get the inverse of $10 \bmod 11^2$, which is $109$.